# Same machine succeeds to connect to WiFi network in Ubuntu but fails in Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, networking, wifi, networkmanager

On Ubuntu 18.04 I can successfully connect to my 5 GHz 802.11n network. In Debian 11 the same machine fails to connect to the same network, but still succeeds in connecting to a 2.4 GHz one.

`nmcli` suggested a filter for looking in the journal. Here's an excerpt of that output:

```
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.7617] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.8026] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.8248] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My-Access-Point' has security, but secrets are required.
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.8266] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.8497] sup-iface[bbe248a51c8dfb35,0,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.9203] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.9338] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 24 14:40:13 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567613.9401] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My-Access-Point' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
jan 24 14:40:16 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567616.7124] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 24 14:40:20 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567620.7952] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
jan 24 14:40:21 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567621.1954] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 24 14:40:25 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567625.3311] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
jan 24 14:40:26 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567626.2471] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 24 14:40:30 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567630.3116] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
jan 24 14:40:35 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567635.2603] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 24 14:40:39 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <warn>  [1674567639.3182] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
jan 24 14:40:39 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567639.3277] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 24 14:40:39 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <warn>  [1674567639.3450] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'My-Access-Point'
jan 24 14:40:39 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567639.3702] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
jan 24 14:40:39 nc10 NetworkManager[474]: <info>  [1674567639.3724] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

"Association" apparently took too long.
I'm not sure what to do about it though. Does it suggest a particular problem?

---

##### Additional info

- There is one additional machine that exhibit similar connection problems to the same access point, in Ubuntu 22.10. The problem does not exist in macOS or Windows 10 on that same machine.
- The access point is a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04.
- Both problematic (in Linux) network adapters are Broadcom-branded
- The failure is consistent
- Distance to the AP makes no difference
- iPhone 5 & 8 can connect successfully to the network

Comment: Did you install the proprietary Broadcom drivers?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes. I wasn't aware there were any other working drivers. Ubuntu provided them with their tool, and I have some memory of having to install it manually on Debian